# PHP - Trying to update multiple mysql values based on if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a points/rewards system, the problem I'm facing is I'm querying the database like so;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE usertype='group_two' ORDER BY 
points DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<li class='select-area'><label><span>" . $row['firstname'] . "</span>";
echo "<span>" . $row['lastname'] . "</span>";
echo "<span>" . $row['points'] . "</span><span><input type='checkbox' 
name='receipient_id'
value=" . $row['id'] ." /></span></label></li>";
}
```

This lists the users that are able to receive points, and that works fine, but If I select multiple users it only sends points to the last checked user, where I would like it to send points to all checked users.

My update query is as follows;

```
$update_query="UPDATE users u1 JOIN users u2
ON u1.id = '$sender_id' AND u2.id= receipient_id
SET u1.points = '$sender_updated_points',
u2.points = '$receiver_updated_points';";
```

Are there any specific tricks I have missed using checkboxes to select multiple rows for updating? I've been googling for around 16 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `name` property of checkboxes as an array like

```
<input type='checkbox' name='receipient_id[]' value=" . $row['id'] ." />
                                          ^
```

In this way, when the form with the selected checkboxes is send to the PHP script, the variable: `$_POST['receipient_id']` will contain a numeric Array with the values of the selected checkboxes, having the index: 0, 1, 2,etc  in their order.

`$_POST['receipient_id'][0]` will be the value of the first selected checkbox and `$_POST['receipient_id'][1]` will be the value of the second selected checkbox and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, when trying this I'm getting an error which won't let me send points to that ID.

Comment: It's triggering this;

if(isset($_GET['receipient_id'])==('invalid'))
{
echo "You have selected an invalid ID";
}

Comment: How you are passing the values to the PHP page?

Comment: <form action="store.php" method="post">

Then the queried data, then:

<select name="points">
   <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"  />

Comment: you are passing data using `POST` method and why you try to accept it using `GET` ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

If you want to send multi values should be in array name="receipient_id" to name="receipient_id[]"

Suggestion on query

```
    $update_query="UPDATE users u1 JOIN users u2
    ON u2.id= u1.receipient_id
    SET u1.points = '$sender_updated_points',u2.points = '$receiver_updated_points'
    where u1.id = '$sender_id';";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i used for the same condition as yours but i use it to delete multiple data that fetched from database

first in you while..loop
- give the name as array

```
<input type="checkbox" id="updcbx" name="updcbx[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
```

than in your php submission, you can use code like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    if (is_array($_POST['updcbx']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['updcbx'] as $upd)
        {
            $update[$upd] = $upd;
            $sql = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = 'value' WHERE id = '$delete[$upd]'";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you :)